# Posting on facebook users wall without the authorization of an application by user

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I'm creating an application that post some text to users wall when they loading my app. Is there any way to do this without the authorization of an application by the user? 
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you think it should be able to do that? Authorization is there for a reason.

Comment: I think it would be logical to ask the user for permission to add а message to his wall, but don't require the authorization of the application.

Comment: Without that permission being tied to a specific app, the user would have to give said permission over and over again if this functionality was to be used multiple times. So it’s a good thing permissions are tied to the app requesting them, because it makes for a much better flow and therefor better user experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Impossible. Facebook would be spammed by now if they would allow that.